# I am trying to make a field for a model which is unique for the choices but could be blank or null

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a field in a model that I would like to be a choice or blank. There may be as many blank items as possible but need to be unique for all others ie there may not be two specials on the same day.

Here is my views.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'), ('Salad', 'Salad'), ('Slider', 'Slider'), ('Side', 'Side'), ('Drink', 'Drink'))
    DAYS = (('Monday','Monday'), ('Tuesday','Tuesday'), ('Wednesday','Wednesday'), ('Thursday','Thursday'), ('Friday','Friday'), ('Saturday','Saturday'), ('Sunday','Sunday'))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DAYS, unique=True, blank=True)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False),
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am also trying to order the daily specials by day of the week ie (Monday, Tuesday, etc) and I thought the following view was working but it seems to be ordering the Items by id

```
def specials(request):
    specials_list = Item.objects.filter(special = True).order_by('day')
    context = {
        'specials_list': specials_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/specials.html', context)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "I have a field in a model that I would like to be a choice or blank." - which field are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices)

> Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. **(None, 'Your String For Display')**. Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField.

So, for you to allow for a blank choice in any of your tuples, just add the bolded text from the above quote

eg:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'), ('Salad', 'Salad'), ('Slider', 'Slider'), ('Side', 'Side'), ('Drink', 'Drink'), ('None', 'N/A'))
```

As for being unique, you already have the days of the week set as unique.